# Botão "voltar e avançar" do navegador e div dinamica sem refresh

Tags: php, html, jquery, navegador-de-internet

Eu e um amigo andamos tendo alguns problemas com o jQuery..

Se baseamos em um código para fazer o botão **voltar e avançar** do navegador funcionar em nosso site, com a função de uma div atualizar sem refresh...

 O código está funcionando em partes, porém estou tendo que lidar com os seguintes erros:
**1º Quando entro na página 1, em seguida na página 2 e tento voltar pela seta do navegador, o conteúdo, titulo do site e url buga.**

Segue o código:

```html
<?php
$isXHR = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'XMLHTTPREQUEST';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Inicio</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var load = function (url) {
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
   var title =  $(data).filter('title').text();
   $("title").html(title);
            $("#content").html(data);
        })
    };

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
            url = $this.attr("href"),
            title = title;

        history.pushState({
            url: url,
            title: title
        }, title, url);

        document.title = title;

        load(url);
    });

    $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if (state !== null) {
            document.title = state.title;
            load(state.url);
        } else {
   //var title =  $(state).filter('title').text();
            //document.title = title;
            $("#content").empty();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (!$isXHR) {
echo "
<ul>
 <li><a href=\"index.php\">Inicio</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"abc.php\">Página 2</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"abc2.php\">Página 3</a></li>
</ul>
";}
?>
<div id="content">Página 1</div>

</body>
</html>
```

abc.php (página 2)

```html
<?php
$isXHR = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'XMLHTTPREQUEST';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Página 2</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var load = function (url) {
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
   var title =  $(data).filter('title').text();
   $("title").html(title);
            $("#content").html(data);
        })
    };

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
            url = $this.attr("href"),
            title = title;

        history.pushState({
            url: url,
            title: title
        }, title, url);

        document.title = title;

        load(url);
    });

    $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if (state !== null) {
            document.title = state.title;
            load(state.url);
        } else {
   //var title =  $(state).filter('title').text();
            //document.title = title;
            $("#content").empty();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (!$isXHR) {
echo "
<ul>
 <li><a href=\"index.php\">Inicio</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"abc.php\">Página 2</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"abc2.php\">Página 3</a></li>
</ul>
";}
?>
<div id="content">Página 2</div>
</body>
```

abc2.php (página 3)

```html
<?php
$isXHR = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'XMLHTTPREQUEST';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Página 3</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var load = function (url) {
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
   var title =  $(data).filter('title').text();
   $("title").html(title);
            $("#content").html(data);
        })
    };

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
            url = $this.attr("href"),
            title = title;

        history.pushState({
            url: url,
            title: title
        }, title, url);

        document.title = title;

        load(url);
    });

    $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
        var state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if (state !== null) {
            document.title = state.title;
            load(state.url);
        } else {
   //var title =  $(state).filter('title').text();
            //document.title = title;
            $("#content").empty();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (!$isXHR) {
echo "
<ul>
 <li><a href=\"index.php\">Inicio</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"abc.php\">Página 2</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"abc2.php\">Página 3</a></li>
</ul>
";}
?>
<div id="content">Página 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sobre possível duplicata... este jeito que vocês informam, não dá pra voltar o conteúdo com a seta do navegador.
Também não deram uma resposta específica.

Comment: Possível duplicata  -->  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276897/problemas-com-jquery

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problemas com Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276897/problemas-com-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para começar, o código de vocês tem bastante problemas. Um deles é que, quando o usuário clica várias vezes, o código só aumenta o número de requisições. Ex:

O usuário entra no site e clica 5 vezes em qualquer um dos links, ao invés de gerar 5 requisições, o código está gerando 31 requisições.

O problema é que vocês estão adicionando **todo** o conteúdo na `div#content`. Isso faz com que o código *JavaScript* seja repetido inúmeras vezes, gerando erros e talvez o *bug* "informado" na pergunta.

Há duas maneiras de corrigir isso:

- Utilizando o [**parseHTML**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) para transformar a resposta em *HTML*. Dessa forma iremos utilizar [**find**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) para capturar nosso elemento (ao invés de adicionar a página toda). Tudo isso no *JavaScript*

```
function load (url, container = "div#content") {
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
        let content = jQuery( "<div>" ).append( jQuery.parseHTML( data ) );
        let title =  $(content).find("title").text();

        $("title").html(title);
        $("#content").html($(content).find(container));
    })
};
```

- Informando o que deve ser renderizado (utilizando o *PHP* e o cabeçalho `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` como base).

```
<?php
$isXHR = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'XMLHTTPREQUEST';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Página 2</title>
        <?php if (!$isXHR) { ?>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         /* Código JS aqui */
        </script>
    </head>

    <?php } ?>
    <body>
    <?php if (!$isXHR) { ?>
    <?php
    echo "
    <ul>
        <li><a href=\"index.php\">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"abc.php\">Página 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"abc2.php\">Página 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    ";}
    ?>
    <div id="content" data-title="Título da página dois">Página 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

> De preferência, escolham as alterações com JS.

Outra coisa, joguem tudo dentro de um arquivo *JavaScript*. Pode parecer bobagem ou é só por que está testando, mas fica complicado trabalhar com vários códigos **idêntico**, as vezes vocês corrigem o erro em um e não percebe que esqueceu outros.

*Adicionei alguns comentários no código.*

```
$(function () {
    function load (url, callback, container = "div#content") {
        $.get(url).done( data => {
            let content = jQuery( "<div>" ).append( jQuery.parseHTML( data ) );
            let title =  $(content).find("title").text();

            document.title = title;

            $("title").html(title);
            $("#content").html($(content).find(container));

            /**
             * Verifica se a variável callback é função
             * Caso seja, retorna true (sucesso)
             */
            if ( (typeof callback) == "function" ) {
                callback(true);
            }

        }).fail( () => {

            /**
             * Verifica se a variável callback é função
             * Caso seja, retorna false (falha)
             */
            if ( (typeof callback) == "function" ) {
                callback(false);
            }
        })
    };

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        /**
         * Carrega a URL a depender do resultado manipula o histórico
         * Ou exibe um lerta
         */
        load($(this).attr("href"), (result) => {
            if (result) {
                /**
                 * Na lógica de programação, você deve ter sucesso ou falha
                 * em algo para exibir uma mensagem ou alterar algum
                 * outro elemento da página
                 */
                history.pushState({
                    url: $(this).attr("href"),
                    title: $("title").text()
                }, $("title").text(), $(this).attr("href"));
            } else {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
    });

    $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {

        console.log( e.originalEvent.state );

        let state = e.originalEvent.state;
        if (state !== null) {
            document.title = state.title;
            load(state.url);
        }
    });

    /* Adiciona a primeira página no histórico */
    history.pushState({
        url: window.location.href,
        title: $("title").text()
    }, $("title").text(), window.location.href);
});
```

> O código está 100%? Não. Mas vou deixar isso a cargo de vocês.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado por tudo!

Comment: Obrigado por tirar um pouquinho do seu tempo pra ajudar pessoas que nem conhece, se precisar de mim pra alguma coisa, apesar de não ser lá grande coisa... pode contar comigo! facebook.com/er1cckz

Comment: Feito! dei feedback positivo.

Comment: Valdeir sobre as requisições do primeiro código, funcionou perfeitamente! porém ainda assim continuamos tendo problemas com o sistema na questão de voltar página duas vezes, procuramos alguns tópicos aqui no Stackoverflow pra ver se conseguíamos sem ter que ficar reabrindo o atual tópico, porém não achei nada que pudesse resolver, você foi a única pessoa que conseguiu me dar uma possível salvação até agora, como posso proceder?

Comment: @ErickPereira Eu editei o código JS agora a pouco, se possível copia e cola e testa novamente. Fiz um teste em localhost e aparentemente funcionou.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste no localhost, qualquer coisa te retorno, agradeço a atenção desde já!

Comment: Funcionou, te agradeço de coração! <3